# is this the correct way to optimize MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
  $sql="update users_contain 
  set
  wood_max      =   (Select building_production from building_level where merge_id=$subPrimaryKey and empire_id=$user_empireID) ,
  iron_max      =   wood_max,
  clay_max      =   wood_max
  where user_id =   $user_id";
```

Now there is a question.

will wood_max will always be updated first than iron_max and clay_max. so it is safe to use this way??
i do not want to use inner query for updating the iron_max and clay_max when i know it has same value for all three fields..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this documentation, your UPDATE statement works as you want it to: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-update.html

Test it to be sure, but I think you're fine.

Comment: "This behavior differs from standard SQL." Scary.

Comment: Yeah, that is a bit scary, but since the OP specified MySQL as their database platform, they'll be fine. Care must be taken if supporting multiple database platforms though.

Comment: Thanks! Your link is FINAL.. Like Final Classes..:)